# Como sacar image full de un json en java?

Tags: java, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo este json, como entro dentro de image y saco full q ademas esta dentor de un array

```
{
    "type": "champion",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "spells": [
                {
                    "id": "AatroxQ",
                    "image": {
                        "full": "AatroxQ.png"
                    },
                    "resource": "Sin coste"
                }
```

Tengo esto para sacar name y descripcion y al inetnatr sacar la imagen me da error y no se como hago para conseguir sacar image full???

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.10.1/data/es_ES/champion/Aatrox.json"); 
     JSONObject jsondata = json.getJSONObject("data");
     JSONObject jspj = jsondata.getJSONObject("Aatrox");
   
       JSONArray arrspe = jspj.getJSONArray("spells");
       
       
           String namespell0 = arrspe.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
           String descripcionspell0 = arrspe.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
           
           String imagenspell0 = arrspe.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");
           String imagenspel = arrspe.getJSONObject(0).getString("full");
            System.out.println(imagenspel);
```

Ayuda Por favor necesito ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serie el siguiente codigo:

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.10.1/data/es_ES/champion/Aatrox.json"); 
      JSONObject jsondata = json.getJSONObject("data");
      JSONObject jspj = jsondata.getJSONObject("Aatrox");

        JSONArray arrspe = jspj.getJSONArray("spells");

        JSONObject objeto0 = arrspe.getJSONObject(0);



//            JSONObject namespell0 = objeto0.getJSONObject("name");
//            JSONObject descripcionspell0 = objeto0.getJSONObject("description");

            JSONObject imagenspel = objeto0.getJSONObject("image");
            System.out.println(imagenspel.getString("full"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eres mi dios, muchisimas gracias